# How to get memory address of tables (Te0, Te1, ...) in openssl AES?

Tags: openssl, gdb, aes, symbols, aslr

**The aim** is to get the address of the precomputed tables in the openssl implementation of AES. These tables are contained in the *aes_core.c* file and named Te0, Te1, etc. I am trying to do it using the `info address SYMBOL_NAME` command in `gdb`.

So these are **the steps I followed** so far:

- Disable ASLR (`sudo sysctl kernel.randomize_va_space=0`)
- Compile openssl (version 101e) with `configure -d shared` to keep debugging symbols
- Link a program to the above mentioned version of openssl (I made sure of that using `info sharedlibrary` in gdb)
- Run the program in gdb and use `info address Te0` (or any other table)

**Result**: `No symbol "Te0" in current context.`

The same doesn't happen for, e.g., the function `private_AES_set_encrypt_key` (also in *aes_core.c*). In fact the result, in this case, is: `Symbol "private_AES_set_encrypt_key" is at 0x7ffff7a483f0 in a file compiled without debugging.` which is exactly what I need.

**My idea**: these tables are declared as `static const` so I guess they might be optimized somehow but then again I am intentionally compiling openssl with support for debugging. So why can't I see those symbols in gdb?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It sounds like the symbols are being optimized out. Try building the library with `CFLAGS=-g3 -ggdb -O0`. `-g3` means maximum debugging info is available including `#define's`. With GCC 5.0, you may be able to use `-Og`. However, I've found symbols are still optimized away with `-Og`, so I use `-g3 -O0`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out many modern processors (e.g. Intel Core i3+) implement AES in hardware which leaves *aes_core.c* (and any other AES related C file) out of the compilation. To solve the problem openssl must be compiled with the *./configure* flag *no-hw*. Also the flag *no-asm* might be useful (although I think the tables would still be loaded in memory).

This way I was finally able to see the address using gdb. :)